# Regex for key value pair

Tags: javascript, regex, key-value

I have a regex

```
(\w+)\s*:((?:\w+[-+*%])*?\w+)$
```

that **matches** key value pair like these -

> key:value
>
> key2:value2

But the regex **match** **fails** if the key and value are within quotes like these -

> "key":value
>
> "key2":"value2"

What modification can be done to make the regex match key and value within quotes also ?

Comment: `key and value are within paranthesis` => you mean quoted right?

Comment: yes. I mean quoted.

Comment: You say "within parentheses" (not "paranthesis") but the example you give shows them within double quote marks. Anyway, please do not pick apart object literal syntax with regexps. Why are you trying to do that? Where are these strings coming from, and what are you trying to do with them?

Comment: *yes. I mean quoted.* Then fix your question!

Comment: that was a mistake. fixed the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optional quotes on either side of `key-value` pairs like this:

```
/("?)\b(\w+)\1\s*:\s*("?)((?:\w+[-+*%])*?\w+)\b\3/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLyawL/1)

Take note of group `("?)` that captured an empty string or a double quote. On the other side we use a back-reference `\1` of this group for closing quote.

Comment: I have answered many times problem of escaped quotes but this question didn't ask for it and I don't over engineer a solution unless it is a requirement.

Comment: OP attempted a regex and tagged it with regex. Feel free to post an answer , if you want.

Comment: You're wasting your time in unnecessary argument. SO doesn't prevent anyone from posting a solution as per the poster's understanding.

Comment: @torazaburo This is _very good_ advice, but I think it might be a lot more valuable to the OP (and future visitors) as a separate answer? This answer addresses the stated goals of the question which gives no indication that this format supports escape sequences. (It certainly cannot be JSON, since unquoted keys are permitted.)